# Programmatically added SummaryLinkWebPart doesn't display Links

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I am using below code to Add SummaryLinkWebPart to a Page and also adding few links to that wehbpart. I can see the webpart now on the page but it doesn't have any links inside it. Does anyone know what is wrong with the code?

```
var wpm = web.GetLimitedWebPartManager("Pages/default.aspx", PersonalizationScope.Shared);

SummaryLinkWebPart slwp = new SummaryLinkWebPart();
    for (int counter = 0; counter < list.ItemCount; counter++)
    {
         urlField = list.Items[counter]["URL"].ToString().Split(',');

         SummaryLink link = new SummaryLink(urlField[1].Trim());
         slwp.SummaryLinkValue.SummaryLinks.Add(link);
         slwp.SummaryLinkValue.SummaryLinks[counter].OpenInNewWindow = true;
         slwp.SummaryLinkValue.SummaryLinks[counter].LinkUrl = urlField[0].Trim();
         slwp.SummaryLinkValue.SummaryLinks[counter].Description = urlField[1];
         slwp.Style = "Image on left";
         Console.WriteLine(link.LinkUrl + link.Title);
    }

    wpm.AddWebPart(slwp, lvwp.ZoneID, slwp.ZoneIndex + 1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm this seems to be the hack but the only thing that solves this issue is reassigning the SummaryLinkValue Property back again its value.

slwp.SummaryLinkValue = slwp.SummaryLinkValue;

Answer (score 1):

use

```
SPLimitedWebPartManager wpManager = page.GetLimitedWebPartManager(System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.Shared);
```

then when done call `page.Update()`. something like this

```
SPFile page = web.GetFile(string.Format("Pages/{0}", this.FileName.Replace("html", "aspx")));
SPLimitedWebPartManager wpManager = page.GetLimitedWebPartManager(System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.Shared);
SummaryLinkWebPart webpart = new SummaryLinkWebPart();

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(RelatedTopic1))
    webpart.SummaryLinkValue.SummaryLinks.Add(GetSummaryLink(web, pages, RelatedTopic1));
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(RelatedTopic2))
    webpart.SummaryLinkValue.SummaryLinks.Add(GetSummaryLink(web, pages, RelatedTopic2));
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(RelatedTopic3))
    webpart.SummaryLinkValue.SummaryLinks.Add(GetSummaryLink(web, pages, RelatedTopic3));
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(RelatedTopic4))
    webpart.SummaryLinkValue.SummaryLinks.Add(GetSummaryLink(web, pages, RelatedTopic4));
if (webpart.SummaryLinkValue.SummaryLinks.Count > 0)
{
    wpManager.AddWebPart(webpart, "BottomPanel", 0);
    page.Update();
}
```